# Spring data rest in production

Tags: java, spring-boot, architecture, spring-data, spring-data-rest

The use of Spring Data Rest is definitely a way to create applications really fast.

But keeping in mind the future production environment, I really want to know if it is a good idea to mix the endpoints in a @RestController (where you will call a service with business validations and logics) with query endpoints generated by the rest repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is based on the **Hypermedia-Driven RESTful Web Service** principle, it is great but depends on various use cases. Look for articles on **Hypermedia-Driven RESTful Web Service** and you will learn some good things also.

It is good - very good for **insensitive** data, which is generally available to all.

And quite good for data where you don't need any orchestration, as it would be direct from the db.

The only concern could be **having them secured(the endpoints)** under some super user type role in your application so that normal user(s) cannot access it.

It would again depend on the use case of your application.

If it is **highly sensitive data**, then it should not be used as data will available through the APIs and data would be compromised

Or having **separate application** which could reside in the premises of the application developing organisation only

Comment: I think what you are saying is really interesting. And what do you think about the "cleaning" of the code? Being more clear, do you think that if the application really grows and you are still mixing Rest controllers with data rest repositores, you can keep the code organized and readable for a developer team? Or you think that given a certain point of complexity, you should unify how you expose your endpoints?

Comment: for complex situations it should not be that great idea I guess

Comment: for complex solutions normal `RestControllers` should be better

Answer (score 0):

It should be good way to go ahead.

But as per my opinion, you should create separate controllers and services for different modules instead of putting all your REST API endpoints in one controller and creating only a single service.

By doing so, it would be easy for you to manage and debug your code in case of any issue is produced.